# Calculating maximum number of overlapping calls

Tags: excel, timestamp, calculated-columns

I have the list of the calls made on my PBX system with start and end timestamps. I want to check the maximum number of concurrent calls for each call.

EG:

| Start time | End time | WRONG concurrency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/9/22 10.19.29 | 15/9/22 10.20.45 | 1 |
| 15/9/22 10.28.16 | 15/9/22 10.28.50 | 2 |
| 15/9/22 10.28.27 | 15/9/22 10.29.41 | 2 |
| 15/9/22 10.29.50 | 15/9/22 10.33.54 | **6** |
| 15/9/22 10.30.58 | 15/9/22 10.31.43 | 2 |
| 15/9/22 10.32.17 | 15/9/22 10.32.18 | 2 |
| 15/9/22 10.32.36 | 15/9/22 10.32.45 | 2 |
| 15/9/22 10.32.58 | 15/9/22 10.33.01 | 2 |

My calculation is made using the formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(($a$2:$a$8<b2)*($b$2:$b$8>a2))`

As you can see for the fourth line it gives the wrong result. The correct value should be **2** as during the interval 10.29->10.33 there are never more than 2 concurring calls.

Any idea how to correct my formula?
If possible I'd like to have it done without VBA.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving here the solution I've found. It doesn't give the exact number of concurrent calls for all cases but it's good enough for me.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8<=F2)*(F2<=$B$2:$B$8))`

This gives as a result the number of active calls at the time the call starts. If a long call starts it may have 1 but there may be subsequent concurring calls. Those will have the correct number calculated and this is enough for my purpose.

I choose <= instead of < because this will be used for capacity statistics and I prefer to be on the safe side; strict < may be more appropriate for you.